# I want to cut the top of the rectangles at an angle using illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Here's my original logo image:

[image]

I want to create a diagonal cut effect as in the following :

[image]

What I'm currently doing is the following :

[image]

I'm making the illusion that the image is cut but using a rectangle (which is shown in red here but normally would be with white borders) that is rotated. Now, when I export the image in illustrator, I get the first image result. However, my problem is that this works well on a white background but does not on any other background since we clearly see the rectangle in white on a black background per say.

How can I manage to cut the edge of the rectangles to produce the desired effect without using a big rectangle that would be shown on a color background.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the basic steps based on Illustrator CS 5. It helps if you turn on the chessboard pattern in the background that makes transparent areas visible. (View > Show Transparency Grid).

1) First draw your frame objects using the **pen tool** or any of the **shape drawing tools** (rectangle, circle, etc.). This gives you vector paths, of which you adjust the stroke *widths and colours* as you like:

[image]

2) Then select and *expand* the path objects. Expanding means converting each thick and thin stroke into shape objects. (You might want to make a copy of the paths  before this step, so you don't need to recreate it from scratch should you decide to change the stroke widths later on): **Select everything and choose Object > Expand…**:

3) To cut the shapes, draw a path (can be a line, a rectangle or circle, etc.) above the shape objects: e.g. use the Line Segment drawing tool and draw a line in your preferred angle, place it over the shapes where you want to cut:
[image]

Then choose **Object > Path > Divide Objects Below**. This adds anchor points to the shape objects where the line you draw crosses them:

[image]

4) Now you can simply use the **Direct Selection** tool (white arrow) or the **Lasso** tool to select and discard the parts you don't want anymore (select + press the delete key):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs, you might also want to consider a clipping mask. It keeps the original elements intact but masks out what you want to hide.

1. Draw your base shape (the three angled rules).
2. Draw a triangle over it like a frame.
3. Select all the objects (making sure your cropping/masking object is on top) and choose <kbd>Object</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Clipping mask</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Make</kbd>.

Look up Clipping masks in the documentation. Interacting with them is not difficult but it is different from other types of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use shapes for the lines, and subtract one of them. This method is useful to solve your issue using Photoshop:

[image]

By selecting your multiple shapes layer you can then click on subtract from the space area:

[image]

**Then select the polygon tool, set sides to 3, drag the mouse to get the triangle shape in place, and subtract the shape.**